# DRF set auth_token to httponly cookie

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use djoser library for TokenAuthentication. But I don't want to send access_token to frontend. Because it can't save it in a secure way. So I changed TokenCreateView in this way:

```
from djoser.views import TokenCreateView
class TokenCreateView(TokenCreateView):

    def _action(self, serializer):
        token = utils.login_user(self.request, serializer.user)
        token_serializer_class = settings.SERIALIZERS.token
        
        response = Response() 
        data = token_serializer_class(token).data

        response.set_cookie(
            key = 'access_token', 
            value = data['auth_token'],
            secure = False,
            httponly = True,
            samesite = 'Lax'
        )

        response.data = {"Success" : "Login successfully","data":data}
        return response
```

I put access_token to httponly cookies. And created a middleware:

```
def auth_token(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        # when token is in headers in is not needed to add in from cookies
        logger.error(request.COOKIES.get('access_token'))

        if 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' not in request.META:

            token = request.COOKIES.get('access_token')
            if token:

                request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = f'Token {token}'

        return get_response(request)

    return middleware

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'apps.profiles.middlewares.auth_token',
    ...
]
```

This middleware adds access_token from cookies to headers. Now the frontend doesn't have an accecc to auth_token. And it is more difficult to steal the auth_token.
Is this approach appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing this. I was looking for an alternative to storing access tokens in local storage for the same reasons - it's not secure. There are a few things I changed or added.

In the create token view, I do not return the token on the response -- my react front-end no longer has to manage it. I am also ensuring that outside of local development, the cookie is secure. Note that the 30-day `max_age` is probably not a great idea for most sites.

```
class TokenCreateView(djoser.views.TokenCreateView):
    def _action(self, serializer):
        token = utils.login_user(self.request, serializer.user)
        token_serializer_class = settings.SERIALIZERS.token

        response = Response()
        data = token_serializer_class(token).data

        response.set_cookie(
            key = "access_token",
            value = data["auth_token"],
            max_age = timedelta(days=30),
            secure = not is_localhost,
            httponly = True,
            samesite = "Strict"
        )

        response.data = "Welcome!"
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
        return response
```

I think you should also delete the cookie on logout.

```
class TokenDestroyView(djoser.views.TokenDestroyView):
    """Use this endpoint to logout user (remove user authentication token)."""

    permission_classes = settings.PERMISSIONS.token_destroy

    def post(self, request):
        response = Response()
        response.delete_cookie("access_token")
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT
        utils.logout_user(request)
        return response
```

I also simplified the middleware function because I choose not to support anything but a cookie.

```
def auth_token(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        token = request.COOKIES.get('access_token')
        if token:
            request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = f'Token {token}'

        return get_response(request)

    return middleware
```

And for completeness, we do need to update the urls.

```
      # path("auth/", include("djoser.urls.authtoken")),
      path("auth/token/login/", core_views.TokenCreateView.as_view(), name="login"),
      path("auth/token/logout/", core_views.TokenDestroyView.as_view(), name="logout"),
```